# Testing controller Action that uses User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have an action that relies on User.Identity.Name to get the username of the current user to get a list of his orders:

```
public ActionResult XLineas()
    {
        ViewData["Filtre"] = _options.Filtre;
        ViewData["NomesPendents"] = _options.NomesPendents;
        return View(_repository.ObteLiniesPedido(User.Identity.Name,_options.Filtre,_options.NomesPendents));
    }
```

Now I'm trying to write unit tests for this, but I get stuck on how to provide a Mock for User.Identity.Name. If I run my test as I have it (without mock for User...), I get a Null.. exception.

Which is the correct approach for this? I'm thinking that my Action code is not good for unit testing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A better way of doing this would be to pass a `string` argument `userName` (or an `IPrincipal` argument `user`, if you need more information than just the name) to the ActionMethod, which you "inject" in a normal request using an ActionFilterAttribute. When you test it, you just supply your own mock object, as the action filter's code will not run (in most cases - there are ways to, if you specifically want to...)

Kazi Manzur Rashid describes this in detail under point 7 in an [excellent blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160629112111/http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1).

Comment: Great. I have to look more into ActionFilters... Thanks.

Comment: I often mock IPrincipal for my tests. It allows me to test user informations (username) but also authorization (User.Identity.IsInRole).

Comment: So do I. On the other hand, mocking IPrincipal just for getting access to the current user's username - and *nothing* else - is on the edge of overkill... :)

Comment: When passing an IPrincipal or IIdentity object, you'll need to use an interface and wrapper. Just using the ActionFilter will result in an error saying you can't implement an interface.

Comment: The article by Kazi Manzur Rashid gives a great starting point. I prefer to modify the code to throw an InvalidOperationException immediately if the user is not authorized. Also note that you should probably write units tests for your ActionFilterAttribute anyway, and will still have to mock these things at least once.

Comment: @rob: Thanks for making me aware. The post is quite old (it wasn't brand new when I wrote this answer over 7 years ago...) and I can't find it archived anywhere either. However, a lot has happened in the ASP.NET landscape since then, so I bet there are other articles describing newer solutions to similar problems.

Comment: @rob: I did find the article in [the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org), though - link updated :D

Answer (score 67):

You can use this code

```
public SomeController CreateControllerForUser(string userName) 
{
    var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns(userName);
    mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

    var controller = new SomeController();
    controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;

    return controller;
}
```

It uses [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) mocking framework, but sure you can use anything you like.

Comment: For anyone else, like me, who was wondering: this code sample uses [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Comment: In WebAPI i did like this
``MyController controller = new MyController();
            controller.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username, "Passport"), new[] { "tester" });``

Comment: @Ravi How? [Controller.User is not settable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user)(though this might have changed in the past 2.5 years)

Comment: @Wolfzoon I have to be honest. I am no more using DotNet. Did not remember answering this :-). Forgive me.