# Writing Unit Test for methods that use User.Identity.Name in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, unit-testing, identity

I am writing test cases using the Unit Test for ASP.NET Web API.

Now I have an action which makes a call to some method I have defined in the service layer, where I have used the following line of code.

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
// do something with username
// return something
```

Now how to I create unit test method for this, I am getting null reference exceptions. I am kinda new to writing unit test and stuff.

I want to use Unit Test only for this. Please help me out on this.

Comment: are you trying to test the action method or the service layer method?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The below one is only one way of doing this:

```
public class FooController : ApiController {

    public string Get() {

        return User.Identity.Name;
    }
}

public class FooTest {

    [Fact]
    public void Foo() {

        var identity = new GenericIdentity("tugberk");
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
        var controller = new FooController();

        Assert.Equal(controller.Get(), identity.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an xUnit thing. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Its worth noting that this solution doesn't work for MVC controllers...only API controllers.

Comment: Only User.Identity.Name is working perfectly but not the method User.Identity.GetUserId()

Comment: @tugberk How to achive the same in mvc controller?

Answer (score 17):

Here's another way I found in the `NerdDinner` testing tutorial. It worked in my case:

```
DinnersController CreateDinnersControllerAs(string userName)
{

    var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns(userName);
    mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

    var controller = CreateDinnersController();
    controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;

    return controller;
}

[TestMethod]
public void EditAction_Should_Return_EditView_When_ValidOwner()
{

    // Arrange
    var controller = CreateDinnersControllerAs("SomeUser");

    // Act
    var result = controller.Edit(1) as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result.ViewData.Model, typeof(DinnerFormViewModel));
}
```

Make sure you read the full section: [Mocking the User.Identity.Name property](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part12.htm)

It uses the `Moq` mocking framework that you can install in your `Test project` using NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/moq

Comment: yes I have recently started using Moq for my new project, will surely consider this approach fr next time

Comment: I just wrote this answer because the accepted one did not work in my case. Don't know why... :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this answer more applies to MVC than Web API. Might be why the accepted answer didn't work for you

Answer (score 11):

With WebApi 5.0 this is slightly different. You can now do:

```
controller.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(
  new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("user"), null));
```

Comment: I'm looking at v5.2.0.0 of `Controller` in System.Web.Mvc.dll, and `IPrincipal User` only has a `get`, no `set`...

Answer (score 1):

None of this ended up working for me, I used the solution on another question which uses Moq to set up a user name in the ControllerContext: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6752924/347455

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Nikita"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "1")
};

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
IPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

controller.User = user;
```

Comment: "Property or indexer 'ControllerBase.User' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Answer (score 0):

Here i found the solution for another way that how to set the user identity name for the controller level testing from the test method.

```
public static void SetUserIdentityName(string userId)
        {
            IPrincipal principal = null;
            principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userId), 
            new string[0]);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of Controllers to Test then I Would Suggest to create a base class and in the constructor create a `GenericIdentity` & `GenericPrincipal` and set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`

```
GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new 
    GenericIdentity("UserName"),null); Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

Then Inherit that class .. So that way every Unit Test class will have Principle Object Set

```
[TestClass]
public class BaseUnitTest
{
    public BaseUnitTest()
    {
      GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("UserName"),null);   
      Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class AdminUnitTest : BaseUnitTest
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void Admin_Application_GetAppliction()
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run Unit test - in my case it uses Windows authentication and Identity.Name is my domain name, which I also want to change for the test.
So I use [such approach with 'hacking' things I want in IAuthenticationFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45629765/208272)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if AspNetCore changed a lot, but nowadays in Net7 you can simply do this

```
someController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
{
    User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName) , new []{string.Empty})
};
```

An example with a working unit test

```
[Test]
public async Task GetAll_WhenUserNotExist_ReturnsNotFound()
{
    // arrange
    var autoMock = AutoMock.GetLoose();

    const string userName = "harry@potter.com";

    var customersServiceMock = autoMock.Mock<ICustomerService>();
    customersServiceMock
        .Setup(service => service.GetAll(userName)).Throws<UserDoesNotExistException>();
    
    var customerController = autoMock.Create<CustomerController>();

    //
    // Create a new DefaultHttpContext and assign a generic identity which you can give a user name 
    customerController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
    {
        User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName) , new []{string.Empty})
    };

    var httpResult = await customerController.GetAllCustomers() as NotFoundResult;
    
    // act
    Assert.IsNotNull(httpResult);
}
```

The implementation of the controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        // User identity name will return harry@potter now.
        var userName = User.Identity?.Name;
        try
        {
            var customers = await _customerService.GetAll(userName).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return Ok(customers);
        }
        catch (UserDoesNotExistException)
        {
            Log.Warn($"User {userName} does not exist");
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```