# Update: Passing HttpContext and IPrincipal to Controler in ReSharper unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit, resharper, iprincipal

I'm attempting to run a couple basic unit tests on an ASP MVC controller, however at one point the controller needs to examine the `IPrincipal` `User` object like so:

```
ViewBag.Level = Security.GetLevel(User);
```

Once the unit test enters the `Create` controller method, however, the above line throws a `NullReferenceException` as the `User` object is `null`.

Any ideas on how to set an `IPrincipal` for a unit test session?

Here's the test as I have it written right now. I attempted to access the `User` object and simply set it before the test goes into the `Create` method, however the intellisense isn't picking it up.

```
    [Test]
    public void a06_CloneFromDatabase()
    {
        using (AgentResources db = new AgentResources())
        {
            var master = (from a in db.AgentTransmission
                          where a.RecordStatus.Equals("C")
                          select a).FirstOrDefault();



            var result = _controlAgtTran.Create(master.ID, null, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, false) as ViewResult;
            var model = result.Model as AgentTransmission;

            Assert.AreEqual(model.ReferenceType, master.ReferenceType);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Following the post mentioned in the comments below I found a method to create a `HttpContext` session and apply and `IPrincipal` to that session. This works fine until the unit test moves into the controller where the `HttpContext` and `IPrincipal` `User` objects are all, once again, null.

Since it seems the instance of the controller I'm using has it's `HttpContext` property as read only (and the `IPrincipal` `User` property as well) does anyone know of a way to pass the `HttpContext` being used in the unit test inside the controller being tested? Also, if this is not possible, what is a usable method for testing `RouteValues` using ReSharper's unit tests?

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _controlAgtTran = new AgentTransmissionController();

        /****Set up Current HTTP Context to pass Security.cs checks*****/

        //Set up the HTTP Request
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost:2574/", "");

        //Set up the HTTP Response
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());

        //Set up the HTTP Context
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

        var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("NEAROD",
                                                             new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                             new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(),
                                                             100,
                                                             true,
                                                             HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                                             SessionStateMode.InProc,
                                                             false);

        httpContext.Items["AspSession"] =
            typeof (HttpSessionState)
                .GetConstructor(
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                    null,
                    CallingConventions.Standard,
                    new[] {typeof (HttpSessionStateContainer)},
                    null)
                .Invoke(new object[] {sessionContainer});

        //Assign the context
        HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
    }

    [Test]
    public void a01_IncompleteRecordGoesToEdit()
    {

        AgentTransmission agtTran = new AgentTransmission();
        agtTran.ReferenceNumber = 95820518787;
        agtTran.ReferenceType = "S";
        agtTran.EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now;
        agtTran.RelationshipEffDate = DateTime.Now;
        agtTran.RecordStatus = "N";
        agtTran.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        agtTran.CreatedOperator = "xTest1";
        agtTran.FirstName = "Unit";
        agtTran.LastName = "Test";
        agtTran.ExtRepType = "EXTREPID";
        agtTran.JIT = true;
        agtTran.SendToDRM = true;
        agtTran.SendToNMF = true;
        agtTran.WelcomeLetter = true;
        agtTran.OverrideRegionInd = false;

        //set IPrincipal 
        string[] roles = {"LCO"};
        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("SYMETRA\\NEAROD"), roles);
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;

        Assert.AreEqual(user, principal); //This passes
        Assert.AreEqual(principal, _controlAgtTran.User); //this fails

        var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)_controlAgtTran.Create(agtTran); //this crashes

        //Tests aren't run
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, result.RouteValues.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("AgentTransmission", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Edit", result.RouteValues["action"]);
    }
```

Comment: I'm no MVC expert but this seems to do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780185/writing-unit-test-for-methods-that-use-user-identity-name-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a similar solution mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497575/asp-net-mvc-unit-test-controller-with-httpcontext) post I added the following to the end of the `SetUp()` method.

```
        var controllerCtx = new ControllerContext();
        controllerCtx.HttpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        _controlAgtTran.ControllerContext = controllerCtx;
```

Wrapping the current `HttpContext` inside an `HttpContextBase` property (the inappropriately named `controllerCtx.HttpContext`) the test now has access to the `User` and `HttpContext` properties of the controller. These properties were previously read-only when using just the `HttpContext.Current` session and therefore always null.

FYI - this is my first time unit testing with these objects so that explanation may be less than 100% correct. Please feel free to comment below and I'll make any necessary changes.