# Error when mocking HttpContextBase

Tags: c#, vb.net, rhino-mocks

I'm using Rhino Mocks to generate a Mock object.  I have the following unit test

```vb
<TestClass()> Public Class VariousTests
  Dim mocks As New MockRepository()
  Dim _mockContext = mocks.PartialMock(Of HttpContextBase)()
  Dim _mockRequest = mocks.PartialMock(Of HttpRequestBase)()

<TestMethod()> Public Sub btnSubmitPage1_ClickTest()
    Dim uri As New Uri("http://mypcname.local")
    SetupResult.For(_mockContext.Request).Return(_mockRequest)
    SetupResult.For(_mockContext.Request.Url).Return(uri)
    SetupResult.For(_mockContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).Return(uri) 'Error happens here
    HttpContextFactory.SetCurrentContext(_mockContext)
    '...
End Sub

End Class
```

I get an error on the indicated line:

> Additional information: Previous method 'HttpContextBase.get_Request();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.

C# or VB.NET answers are acceptable. How can I get past this error?

Comment: you tried `_mock.Setup( ... ).Returns(...)`? or `_mock.SetupGet( ... ).Returns( ... )`

Comment: @W92 - No, I'm not very skilled with Mock frameworks.  Maybe thats where my problem is.

Comment: maybe it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389744/testing-controller-action-that-uses-user-identity-name/6752924#6752924

Comment: @W92 - I think you are on the right track.  I just need to figure out how to apply this to Rhino Mocks.

Comment: Sorry, but I never using this dll, but maybe (again) it help you: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/rhinomock-fundamentals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote the test in C# and it worked.  What I have now is a little different from the above.  But the difference is small overall. It works now.

```
[TestClass]
public class VertrueSignupViewTests
{
    private SplContextProvider _splProvider = new SplContextProvider();
    private IVertrueSignupView _form = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IVertrueSignupView>();
    private IFeatureToggle _toggle = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFeatureToggle>();
    HttpContextBase mockHttpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
    HttpRequestBase mockRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
    HttpResponseBase mockResponse = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();
    HttpSessionStateBase httpSessionState = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpSessionStateBase>();

    [TestMethod]
    public void ButtonSubmitTest()
    {
        mockHttpContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(mockRequest);
        mockHttpContext.Stub(x => x.Session).Return(httpSessionState);
        mockHttpContext.Stub(x => x.Response).Return(mockResponse);
        _toggle.Stub(t => t.IsOn()).Return(true);

        var uri =
            new Uri(
                "http://mypc.local/");
        mockRequest.Stub(u => u.Url).Return(uri);
        mockRequest.Stub(u => u.QueryString)
            .Return(col);

        HttpContextFactory.SetCurrentContext(mockHttpContext);
        //...
    }
```